# sql java queries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a java object 'star' that consists of two columns, string name (the name of the star) and string List fans (the list of fans of this star). I'd  like to persist this class using JPA1 or hibernate. I've done so using the annotation @collectionOfElements on the list. It works fine, and creates two tables.

Now I'd like to get all stars whose fans are 'alice' or 'bob' or 'charlie'. How can I do that in the easiest way (only one query rather than 3, and without using 'OR' statements if possible), using jpa queries (hibernate if it's a must), and without retrieving the whole list of fans ?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to avoid using `or`? This is meant to be used in such cases.

Comment: If all my other requirements are met, I think I can live with a OR.

Comment: from star where fans in ('alice', 'bob', 'charlie')

Answer (score 1):

The following query should help you:

```
select s.* from star s where s.fans.name in ('alice', 'bob', 'charlie')
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The fans column doesn't exist, it's persisted in another table.

Comment: It's kinda hard to guess without having your code. Could you provide entities and mappings? My example is written in JPAQL, so I assumed your `Star` object has a `List<Fan> fans` attribute.